# Multiple routers on the same network

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, ping

I'm configuring 2 routers both with internet access to the same network. In the network I have the 2 routers, 2 acccess points and some pc connected to an unmanaged switch.
I want people that connects to ap to use router 1 so it's the only one with dhcp enabled (with ip 10.5.50.1) while some specific devices needs to use router 2 (that has dhcp disabled and has ip 192.168.1.1) so i configured them with static ip and gateway 192.168.1.1.
I have a problem and a weird thing that I don't understand why it happens and I'm not sure if it's because of my configuration.
The weird thing is that if I try to ping one pc to another pc statically set (for example ping 192.168.1.10 to 192.168.1.32) the first one always tries to pass through the gateway of the router 1 that shouldn't know about and I don't understand why. then after the first one it reaches the machine. for example:

```
Pinging 192.168.1.32 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.5.50.1: Net destination unreachable
Reply from 192.168.1.32: bytes=32 time=<1ms TTL=255
Reply from 192.168.1.32: bytes=32 time=<1ms TTL=255
Reply from 192.168.1.32: bytes=32 time=<1ms TTL=255
```

The problem is instead that sometimes for some second I can't ping anymore static pcs with 192.168.1.x ip. after a couple of seconds everything runs again. If I detach the 1st router it doesn't happen.
I'm probably missing some big problem with this configuration but I don't understand what I'm missing

Comment: Please post the output of `ipconfig /all` for the PC you are trying to ping *from*. Do any of these PCs have multiple NICs?

Comment: yes it has more than one but all disconnected and without custom settings. here ipconfig: https://pastebin.com/cAmb0r4S